# Adding my own WPF TriggerAction

Tags: .net, wpf

I've been trying to add a custom TriggerAction to our code.  The following is the XAML snippet:

```
<Style x:Key="ToolBarButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown">
            <actions:MyAction />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    ...
```

MyAction is defined as follows:

```
  public class MyAction: TriggerAction<DependencyObject>
  {
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        // Do something
    }
  }
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following exception:

> 1) The given object must be an instance of TriggerAction or a derived type.
>
> Resulting in: 'Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.TriggerActionCollection' threw an exception.' Line number '29' and line position '15'.

I am running Visual Studio 2010, targeting .Net 4.0.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding any TriggerAction under the 'Event Trigger' of Styles expects the action to be of type

```
System.Windows.TriggerAction
```

Your custom action 'My Action' uses the

```
System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerAction<T> (Generic Type)
```

and hence this error. You can try the following. This seems to be working in your case.

```
    <Button Content="Custom Action" Width="150" Height="50">
        <interact:Interaction.Triggers>
            <interact:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
                <actions:MyAction></actions:MyAction>
            </interact:EventTrigger>
        </interact:Interaction.Triggers>            
    </Button>
```

Here, interact is the alias added for Interactivity. Let me know in case you need any more information.

Comment: That fixed the exceptions (thanks!).  Unfortunately the Interaction.Triggers can't be added to a Style, so that means I have to add the trigger to every place I use buttons.  Oh well...